# Why getClass().getResource has problems with RandomAccessFile / ReversedLinesFileReader (Apache Commons)?

Tags: java, eclipse, io

I have my txt file in resources folder (parent folder is project folder), this resources folder is made a source folder (so that Eclipse automatically copies its content to /bin root). Within resources folder I have lottery_archives folder and within it drawArchive_5x36.txt file. I did "Clean Project" and Build it again. I checked - file is present in /bin/lottery_archives/drawArchive_5x36.txt

What is wrong with the code below? Why FileNotFoundException?

And by the way, why are all those dances with getClass().getResource and then URL->String (I need to give String fileName to RandomAccessFile constructor), I do not fully understand why I cannot give String "/lottery_archives/drawArchive_5x36.txt" directly to constructor? I feel that something can be different from jar, not local file, but cannot formulate it clearly.

```
 import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader;

 public String readLastLine5x36() throws IOException {
    String archiveFileName = "/lottery_archives/drawArchive_5x36.txt";
    URL archiveURL = this.getClass().getResource(archiveFileName);      
    String fileName = archiveURL.toString();        
    File file = new File(fileName);     

    ReversedLinesFileReader reader = new ReversedLinesFileReader(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    String result = reader.readLine();
```

archiveURL.toString returns `"file:/L:/MySeriousProjects/JackPotAlert/JackPotAlert/bin/lottery_archives/drawArchive_5x36.txt"`

Error Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: \lottery_archives\drawArchive_5x36.txt (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
at org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader.<init>(ReversedLinesFileReader.java:135)
at org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader.<init>(ReversedLinesFileReader.java:78)
at com.codeuniverse.jackpotalert.domain.Archive.readLastLine5x36(Archive.java:128)
at com.codeuniverse.jackpotalert.domain.Archive.main(Archive.java:139)
```

Attempting to convert URL to URI and give URI into RandomAccessFile constructor (thru apache class)

```
    String archiveFileName = "/lottery_archives/drawArchive_5x36.txt";
    URL archiveURL = this.getClass().getResource(archiveFileName);      
    File file = new File(archiveURL.toURI());
```

produces URISyntaxException.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this.getClass().getResource(archiveFileName)` on a file in your application's jar file.  Because it's not a separate file.

You need to use  `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(archiveFileName)`:

> [public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))
>
> Finds a resource with a given name. The rules for searching resources
>   associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class
>   loader of the class. This method delegates to this object's class
>   loader. If this object was loaded by the bootstrap class loader, the
>   method delegates to
>   ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(java.lang.String).
>
> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the
>   given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> If the name begins with a `'/'` (`'\u002f'`), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the `'/'`.
>   Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
> ```
>     modified_package_name/name
> ```
>
> Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with `'/'` substituted for `'.'` (`'\u002e'`).
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> name - name of the desired resource
> ```
>
> Returns:
>
> ```
>  A InputStream object or null if no resource with this name is found
> ```
>
> Throws:
>
> ```
>   NullPointerException - If name is null
> ```
>
> Since:
>
> ```
>   JDK1.1
> ```

Note that this method returns an `InputStream`, which may limit your options for reading the contents.